# Error when accessing resource file in method with parameter key

Tags: c#, httpcontext

I'm trying to access my global.resx file from a static method... this is what i have

```
public static string GetElementTextLabel(string attributeName)
{
        string retValue = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            retValue = (string) HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Global", attributeName) ?? "(value needed)";  

        }
        catch (NotImplementedException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return retValue;
}
```

I get the following error:
it's giving an error, saying `"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext.get'`

how can i use the parameter in my search for the resource value... if i remove the `static` then it works fine but now i need this method static

Comment: the error is telling you what the problem is.. are you familiar with the difference between Instance and static..?

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as an extension method:

```
public string GetElementTextLabel(this ExtObject obj, string attributeName)
```

Where `obj` is whatever instance of an object you find suitable.

Comment: so how would the code in the method look like then? not familiar with extensions

Comment: The same. `obj` gives you the capability of using the object you are extending but you don't have to. Do a quick search on `c# extension methods`